# Unable to insert multiple records in sql server using php

Tags: php, sql-server

[image]I am facing issues while inserting multiple records in sql server using php.

Here is my query:-

```
 INSERT INTO [BP].[users](id,username,email,contact,status) VALUES
        ('12','sujata','td@hh.com','8588841506','0'),
        ('13','sonali','th@wq.com','7894561231','0'),
        ('14','khushboo','tr@lp.com','7894561230','0')
```

It shows me this error message always:-

> Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
>
> Parse error at line: 2, column: 49: Incorrect syntax near ','.

This is my query from php file:-

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO users(id,username,email,contact,status,num_update) VALUES  $import_data ;
```

This is what import data returns

```
('12','sujata','td@hh.com','8588841506','0'),('13','sonali','th@wq.com','7894561231','0'),('14','khushboo','tr@lp.com','7894561230','0')
```

When I print the query it shows:-

```
INSERT INTO users(id,username,email,contact,status) VALUES ('12','sujata','td@hh.com','8588841506','0'),('13','sonali','th@wq.com','7894561231','0'),('14','khushboo','tr@lp.com','7894561230','0')
```

When I print Sql Error,it shows:-

```
SQLSTATE: 42000
code: 103010
message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Parse error at line: 1, column: 104: Incorrect syntax near ','.
SQLSTATE: 42000 code: 103010 message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Parse error at line: 1, column: 104: Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

Comment: what is the type of your status column ?

Comment: @Lakshitha:-status is varchar.

Comment: Try to remove your schema(i.e. [BP]) and insert data

Comment: @Devika:-Schema name is BP & Table name is users.

Comment: @Lakshitha:- When I enter insert single entry,it works perfect but facing issue with multiple entries.

Comment: Its because SQL cannot distinguish multiple entries when you use them to insert in such a way.

Comment: could you please post your array data with table schema

Comment: @shweta_kaushish your id is auto increment or not

Comment: @RahulShrivastava:-Array data is :- ('12','sujata','td@hh.com','8588841506','0'),('13','sonali','th@wq.com','7894561231','0'),('14','khushboo','tr@lp.com','7894561230','0')

Comment: @RahulShrivastava:-I have pasted the table screenshot above.BP_users is table,all columm are listed

Comment: @shweta_kaushish  remove your schema and try.

Comment: and don't use column name status

Comment: @shweta_kaushish this is not array data post your complete dump data

Comment: @RahulShrivastava:-I am importing a csv into sql server,This is what it returns after parsing that csv..In mysql it's working perfectly but giving errors with sql server

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 INSERT INTO [BP].[users](id,username,email,contact,status)

 select  '12','sujata','td@hh.com','8588841506','0'
  union

select  '13','sonali','th@wq.com','7894561231','0'
 union

select '14','khushboo','tr@lp.com','7894561230','0'
```

Comment: You will have to split (by comma) each entry to distinguished the separate record and shall replace with a union. It is obvious that you have to alter your import date to generate the desired query.
And not to forget you will have to get rid of from the parenthesis as well.

Comment: :-This solution worked..I was able to insert multiple records in sql server only using this way...

Comment: The only issue I am facing now is that each record is inserting twice in database..Any suggestions over this

Comment: Could you upload the code anywhere so that I can have a look? My suggestion is that you need to make sure you generating dynamic correct and only once.

Answer (score 0):

Actually my php skill not wery good. But I suggest an approach for solve a dynamic one. 
First you can parse your string with regex or if value is an array you can loop at other ways

```
    ('12','sujata','td@hh.com','8588841506','0'),
    ('13','sonali','th@wq.com','7894561231','0'),
    ('14','khushboo','tr@lp.com','7894561230','0')
```

Then you can insert per row

Answer (score 0):

if you have `csv` file then you need to do run following code to insert data in table

```
$query = <<<eof
    LOAD DATA INFILE 'your csv file name'
     INTO TABLE BP_users
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (id,username,email,contact,status)
eof;

$db->query($query);
```

Comment: How to create chat room here,will discuss it there

Comment: It seems I dont have previliges to chat..It shows me mssage hereYou must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here.

Comment: you can upload your code with csv file any where and give me url .

Comment: now try https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169402/room-for-rahul-shrivastava-and-shweta-kaushish

Comment: Rahul,Thank you for all your help..You were really  a support in all this troubleshotting!